# Chartkick charts not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been having this issue for a while and would really appreciate some help. I have a chartkick problem. My charts don't show on the front end at all.

My application.js looks like

```
    //= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require icalendar
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require apexcharts
//= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require data-turbolinks-trackn
//= require_gmaps.js
//= require cocoon
//= gmaps
//= require_tree
//= require seems_rateable
//= require_directory ./rateable
 .
```

On the view page it shows code such as

```
<%= area_chart @invoices.where(['invoice_date > ?', 365.days.ago]).group_by_month(:invoice_date).sum(:payment), prefix: "$", suffix: "$", defer: true, download: true, colors: ["#b00", "#333"], legend: "bottom", code: "true", defer: true  %>
```

I have nothing in the header of my application.html.erb and my gem file shows

#Charts for rails chartkick and groupdate to group by date/month/etc
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'chartkick'

As I said, I've been toying with this issue for a while and really want to get it fixed to publish my first iterration of the app. Thanks again. Evan

Comment: What does your javascript console show?

Comment: @Josh Brody thanks so much for the help, you showed me something new! I solved it, I deleted the javascript reference at some point, so glad it's back, I love my charts ! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake here was that I had deleted the reference to the Chartkick javascript, I had accidentally deleted

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

Thanks to Josh for the new info on Java consoles, all the best to you all in this COVID-19 times.