# Chartkick not loading in Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm trying to render the basic line chart using Chartkick (with the default, Chart.js) in Ruby on Rails. I have followed the installation instructions here (https://chartkick.com/#installation) and added:

1. `gem "chartkick"` to the gem file
2. `pin "chartkick", to: "chartkick.js"` and `pin "Chart.bundle", to: "Chart.bundle.js"` to importmap.rb
3. In my application layout, I've added `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>`
4. In User/index.html, I have `<%= line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>`. I have tried a more basic, `<%= line_chart({"2021-01-01" => 2, "2021-01-02" => 3}) %>`.

This render a page that says, "Loading...". An inspection of that page shows,

```
(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute("data-turbolinks-preview")) return;
    if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute("data-turbo-preview")) return;

    var createChart = function() { new Chartkick["LineChart"]("chart-2", [["2021-01-01",2],["2021-01-02",3]], {}); };
    if ("Chartkick" in window) {
      createChart();
    } else {
      window.addEventListener("chartkick:load", createChart, true);
    }
})();
```

Can someone please let me determine what steps I'm missing to show the graph?

Comment: The solution in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110304/chartkick-charts-not-visible worked for me but it doesn't make sense because it uses Google maps, whereas the installation instructions say it uses Chart.js as the default.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, you need to put `<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>` in application.html.erb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Anyone know why is this needed ? Also why is this not on Chartkick's original docs ?

Comment: @AshishGaur I had to use inline javascript because of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173598/rails-7-is-not-importing-javascript-files?noredirect=1#comment137821965_78173598