# Why is rails 7 turbo_frame or turbo_stream not rendering chartkick or rails_chart?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chartkick, turbo, turbo-frames

I am using the following:

```
gem "rails", "7.0.8" 
gem "sprockets-rails"                        
gem "jsbundling-rails"
gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 1.5'  
gem 'stimulus-rails', '~> 1.3'
gem "cssbundling-rails"       
gem 'importmap-rails', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
gem 'rails_charts', '~> 0.0.6'
#gem 'chartkick', '~>5.0.5'
```

With this code below I can basically, follow the flow all the way through.  That is the turbo_stream.update will render the partial, fill in the data, then send the response back to the browser and replace **foobar** with the rails_charts script.  But it seems the script code does not execute and therefore not render chart.  I tried adding console.log JS calls in the partial and these do not render either. When I switch this to a turbo_frame, the test console.log JS calls render, but the chart still does not.  I tried with chartkick as well - same difference.

I looked many of the diff stack overflow Q&A including this one
[Chartkick not loading in Ruby on Rails 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73452250/chartkick-not-loading-in-ruby-on-rails-7)
https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/416
and several others, nothing has helped.

I did see that https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts in the "Contributing section" has "support turbo streams?" - which indicates turbo is not supported - but then I see the JS below and it has the turbo event listeners in there.

I feel this will be an amazing flow if I can get them working.  For now, am reverting back to full page loads sadly until I can sort this out - any thoughts or help possible?

===

```
format.turbo_stream do
   render turbo_stream: [
      turbo_stream.update("avg_wait_area",
                         partial: "wait_stats/avg_wait_chart",
                              locals: { mon_stats: @mon_stats })
        ]
    end


in _avg_wait_chart.turbo_stream.erb
    <div id="avg_wait_area">
      foobar
    </div>



div id="rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc" class="box" style="width: 100%; height: 450px">
          <script>
            if (!window.RailsCharts) {
              window.RailsCharts = {}
              window.RailsCharts.charts = {}
            }

            function init_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc(e) {
              if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute("data-turbolinks-preview")) return;
              if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute("data-turbo-preview")) return;

              <!-- RailsCharts::StackedBarChart -->
              var chartDom = document.getElementById('rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc');

              if (!chartDom) { return }

              var lib = ("echarts" in window) ? window.echarts : echarts;
              var chart = lib.init(chartDom, null, { "locale": null, "renderer": "canvas" });
              var option = {"series":[{"data":[0.24,2.15,3.1,3.1,4.54,5.3,5.77,6.25,9.36,16.81,22.97],"type":"bar","stack":{}}],"xAxis":{"type":"value"},"yAxis":{"type":"category","data":["A","b","c","d","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"]},"tooltip":{"trigger":"axis","axisPointer":{"type":"shadow"}},"toolbox":{"feature":{"saveAsImage":{}}},"title":{"text":"Average Wait Days - Dec-2023"},"visualMap":{"show":false,"min":0,"max":25,"orient":"horizontal"},"grid":{"containLabel":true,"left":0}};
              option && chart.setOption(option);

              window.RailsCharts.charts["rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc"] = chart;
            }

            function destroy_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc(e) {
              var chart = window.RailsCharts.charts["rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc"];
              if (chart) {
                chart.dispose()
              }
              delete window.RailsCharts.charts["rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc"];
            }

            window.addEventListener('load', init_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc);
            window.addEventListener('turbo:load', init_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc);
            window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', init_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc);

            document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-render", destroy_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc);
            document.addEventListener("turbo:before-render", destroy_rails_charts_339d948522be9104817e0757052eebc2663a61dc);
          </script>
        </div>
```

Again, I tried all of the above.

Comment: Beware that all those variables declared with `var` will get hoisted to the top of the function and will be executed before your "guard clause". Use `let` instead. You also have a HTML comment in the middle of your JS.

Comment: That JS code is generated as part of rails_chart automatically.

Comment: Yeah the quality doesn't inspire much confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is none of those events are fired when rendering a *turbo_stream* which means chart is not initialized. Solution is pretty simple: don't use event listeners at all. To make it even better wrap it in Stimulus:

```bash
bin/rails g stimulus chart
```

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/chart_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "echarts";
import "echarts/theme/dark";

// Connects to data-controller="chart"
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    option: Object,
    theme: String,
    locale: String,
    renderer: String,
  }

  connect() {
    if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute("data-turbo-preview")) return;
    this.chart = echarts.init(this.element, this.themeValue, { locale: this.localeValue, renderer: this.rendererValue });
    this.chart.setOption(this.optionValue);
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.chart?.dispose()
  }
}
```

Override [`generate_rails_chart`](https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts/blob/94c212cc87abb6d884e168a06effcee273666051/lib/rails_charts/helpers.rb#L67) helper to use this stimulus controller instead of generating [inline](https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_charts/blob/94c212cc87abb6d884e168a06effcee273666051/lib/rails_charts/base_chart.rb#L34) javascript:

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

# this helper method is used by all the other more specific chart helpers
def generate_rails_chart(klass, data, options = {})
  chart = klass.new(data, options)

  tag.div class: "w-full h-[450px]", data: {
    controller:           :chart,
    chart_option_value:   chart.option,
    chart_theme_value:    chart.theme,
    chart_locale_value:   chart.locale,
    chart_renderer_value: chart.renderer
  }
end
```

Render on a page or in a turbo stream partial:

```rb
<%= line_chart({1=>10, 2=>20, 3=>15}) %>
```

or from controller:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(
      "avg_wait_area",
      helpers.line_chart({1=>10, 2=>20, 3=>15})
    )
  end
end
```

---

This is what should be generated by chart helpers, there is no javascript code here:

```html
<div class="w-full h-[450px]"
  data-controller="chart"
  data-chart-option-value="{&quot;series&quot;:[{&quot;data&quot;:[10,20,15],&quot;type&quot;:&quot;line&quot;}],&quot;xAxis&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;category&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[1,2,3]},&quot;yAxis&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;value&quot;},&quot;tooltip&quot;:{&quot;trigger&quot;:&quot;axis&quot;},&quot;toolbox&quot;:{&quot;feature&quot;:{&quot;saveAsImage&quot;:{}}}}"
  data-chart-renderer-value="canvas"
></div>
```

Stimulus takes care of the rest, regardless of how you render it: on a page or turbo stream. I've tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, this does no render a diagram either.  The turbo_stream sends back the JS without event listeners, but no chart render occurs.  It appears for any JS (ex. console.log()) that is sent back to the div, the JS is not executing.  Is this some sort of security setting that needs to be consodered?

Comment: @gp-coder i'm not sure what you're trying to do, there is no JS being sent in a turbo stream in this set up. only html with data attributes is sent.